# Store libusb devices in easy-access container, without ownership

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'd like to store `libusb_device_handle*`s to be used by multiple clients (one handle can be used by multiple clients), so I thought about storing them with:

```
libusb_open(device, &handle);
libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
auto sharedHandle = std::shared_ptr<libusb_device_handle>(handle, [=](libusb_device_handle* handle) {
    libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);
    libusb_close(handle);
});
```

For reference, a client looks like:

```
struct Client
{
    Client(std::shared_ptr<libusb_device_handle> handle_, uint8_t endpoint_) : handle(handle_), endpoint(endpoint_) {}
    std::shared_ptr<libusb_device_handle> handle;
    uint8_t endpoint;
};
```

When all clients with same `handle` are destroyed the `handle` will also release the interface and close itself, which is great.

Thing is, when a new client is created it might ask an already opened `std::shared_ptr<libusb_device_handle>` (I'm using "Product String" as unique descriptor). I'm not sure how to store these. If I'll use a map to `weak_ptr` I won't be able to create a copy of already-created `shared_ptr`s. If I'll use a map of `shared_ptr`, the device won't ever get deleted because the map will always hold a reference.

What is the best approach here in terms of memory management & containers?

Comment: @S.M. They're asking about the best way to store multiple `shared_ptr`s, not about the best way to create a `shared_ptr`, which they've solved.

Comment: *I won't be able to create a copy of already-created `shared_ptr`s* - what does it mean?

Comment: @S.M. Likely that they don't know the `weak_ptr.lock()` method exists.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Exactly - thanks. You can turn your comment into answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map with `std::weak_ptr`. `weak_ptr` provides a method `lock()` to create a `shared_ptr` from the `weak_ptr` as long as the shared object still exists.

Your map could be something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using libusb_device_handle = ...;
using map_type = std::map<uint8_t, std::weak_ptr<libusb_device_handle>>;
map_type map;

Client get_client(uint8_t endpoint)
{
    auto it = map.find(endpoint);
    if (it != map.end()) {
        return Client(it->second.lock(), endpoint);
    }
    return Client(std::shared_ptr<libusb_device_handle>(), endpoint);
}
```

Please note you will have to check if the `shared_ptr` evaluates to true if it contains a valid libusb_device_handle.